# What does "carvers" and "cleavers" mean in a dialogue in the '6 Underground'?

Tags: dialogue, 6-underground

In the movie [*6 Underground*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6_Underground_(film)) around the `01:26:38` mark a guy shoots another guy and the following dialogue happens:

> His first friend: Nice shot.
>
> Guy that shot: Carvers.
>
> His second friend: Cleavers.

So, I have not used the words "Carvers" and "Cleavers" too often. I googled the words' definitions (such definition that would be appropriate for the dialog). Here are the most appropriate definitions I found:

Carver - a person who cuts and serves the meat at a meal.

Cleaver - a tool with a heavy, broad blade, used by butchers for chopping meat.

So, here is how I understand the dialogue. The guy which has shot says "Carvers" and expects his second friend to either say "Cleavers" or anything else. In case the second friend tells "Cleavers", then that means that the second friend approves the shot, otherwise the second friend is not content with the shot. Do I understand the dialog correctly? Maybe there is an idiomatic expression which is related to these two words (carvers and cleavers)?

Comment: It just means they are a family now. Check the conversation they have after Six dies. Around min 20. I believe Seven said Carvers by mistake and One corrected him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's in relation to an earlier conversation. Round about the 20 minute mark, the crew are on a boat just after

> Six gets killed.

One says "We're not the Cleavers", a family from television's *Leave it to Beaver*.

During the final conversation, Seven mistakenly says "Carver", One corrects him and says "Cleaver", meaning that they are all a family now and no-one gets left behind.

Comment: there is a running joke that no one gets the Leave it To Beaver references ("F-ing millenials") but at least here someone is trying.

Answer (score 1):

**Carvers** - Carvers is probably the surname of Number Seven, AKA Blaine the sniper, AKA “Guy that shot”. It might also be the acronym, CARVER, used by the US Army to determine sniper placement and usage, as well as target analysis. But, I doubt this is the case. It is more likely that he is falling back to his Army habits of addressing each other by last name.

Blaine is a character based on US Army Ranger sniper Sergeant Nicholas “The Reaper” Irving. Some clues to this are the location of his home, Savannah, Georgia. This is also the home of 1st Ranger Battalion. Also, the soldiers performing honor guard at his funeral are all Army Rangers.

Both Blaine and Number One are suffering from forms of survivor’s guilt. Couple this with Blaine’s indoctrination of the Ranger Creed, it would leave Blaine to risk the success of the mission in order to retrieve Billy (Number Four). He would not let the body of a fallen comrade fall into the hands of the enemy.

Also, Blaine’s sense of Esprit de Corp would dictate that he consider his comrades like brothers and sisters. He would get to know his team and treat them like family

> **Ranger Creed**
> **R**ecognizing that I volunteered as a Ranger, fully knowing the hazards of my chosen profession, I will always endeavor to uphold the prestige, honor, and high esprit-de-corps of my Ranger Regiment.
>
> **A**cknowledging the fact that a Ranger is a more elite Soldier who arrives at the cutting edge of battle by land, sea, or air, I accept the fact that as a Ranger my country expects me to move further, faster and fight harder than any other Soldier.
>
> **N**ever shall I fail my comrades. I will always keep myself mentally alert, physically strong, and morally straight and I will shoulder more than my share of the task, whatever it may be, one hundred percent and then some.
>
> **G**allantly will I show the world that I am a specially selected and well-trained Soldier. My courtesy to superior officers, neatness of dress, and care of equipment shall set the example for others to follow.
>
> **E**nergetically will I meet the enemies of my country. I shall defeat them on the field of battle for I am better trained and will fight with all my might. Surrender is not a Ranger word. I will never leave a fallen comrade to fall into the hands of the enemy and under no circumstances will I ever embarrass my country.
>
> **R**eadily will I display the intestinal fortitude required to fight on to the Ranger objective and complete the mission, though I be the lone survivor.
>
> **Rangers Lead the Way!**

**Cleavers** - The surname of the family portrayed in the television series [Leave It to Beaver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leave_It_to_Beaver). They are considered the prototypical if not stereotypical American family of the 1950s. Almost impossibly so. The mother, June, was never seen in anything other than a very wholesome dress, high heels, and pearl jewelry. Even when she was cooking or cleaning the house. The father, Ward, always wore slacks and a shirt and tie with a suit, blazer, or sweater. And, the kids never got into any serious trouble. Just comical shenanigans. The idiomatic use of their name brings up the allusion of unbelievable/unrealistic wholesomeness and family values.

Number One is using the name with (characteristically typical Ryan Reynolds) sarcasm. Number One does not approve of the shot. Nor does he approve of delaying or jeopardizing the mission to save Number Four. He especially does not approve of breaking protocol by using their real names.

Ultimately, this movie is about the transformation of the characters. Unlike Blaine, the rest of the team (including One and Six) do not come from backgrounds or professions that highly value, prize, foster nor nurture loyalty, family, and teamwork. Each team member’s view on loyalty and family is changed right before (Three and Four), during (Two and Five), or after (One) the events of the movie.